# Best practice for interface to allow adding, deleting etc. child objects w/ broadcasting events (similar to ObservableCollection)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I'm trying to specify an interface for a Folder. That interface should allow to
- Add or delete files of type IFile
- Get an List of IFile
- Broadcast events whenever a file was added/deleted/changed (e.g. for the GUI to subscribe to)

and I'm trying to find the best way to do it. So far, I came up with three ideas:

## 1

```
public interface IFolder_v1
{
    ObservableCollection<IFile> files;
}
```

## 2

```
public interface IFolder_v2
{
    void add(IFile);
    void remove(IFile);
    IEnumerable<IFile> files { get; }

    EventHandler OnFileAdded { get; }
    EventHandler OnFileRemoved { get; }
    EventHandler OnFileDeleted { get; }
}
```

## 3

```
public interface IFolder_v3
{
    void add(IFile);
    void remove(IFile);
    IEnumerable<IFile> files { get; }

    EventHandler<CRUD_EventArgs> OnFilesChanged { get; }
}

public class CRUD_EventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public enum Operations
    {
        added,
        removed,
        updated
    }

    private Operations _op;

    public CRUD_EventArgs(Operations operation)
    {
        this._op = operation;
    }

    public  Operations operation
    {
        get
        {
            return this._op;
        }
    }
}
```

Idea #1 seems really nice to implement as doesn't require much code, but has some problems: What, for example, if an implementation of IFolder only allows to add files of specific types (Say, text files), and throws an exception whenever another file is being added? I don't think that would be feasible with a simple ObservableCollection.

Idea #2 seems ok, but requires more code. Also, defining three separate events seems a bit tedious - what if an object needs to subscribe to all events? We'd need to subscribe to 3 different eventhandlers for that. Seems annoying.
Also a little less easy to use than solution #1 as now, one needs to call .Add to add files, but a list of files is stored in .files etc. - so the naming conventions are a bit less clear than having everything bundled up in one simple sub-object (.files from idea #1).

Idea #3 circumvents all of those problems, but has the longest code. Also, I have to use a custom EventArgs class, which I can't imagine is particularly clean in an interface definition? (Also seems overkill to define a class like that for simple CRUD event notifications, shouldn't there be an existing class of some sort?)

Would appreciate some feedback on what you think is the best solution (possibly even something I haven't thought of at all). Is there any best practice?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your input. Seems like opinions on this diverge, and all solutions would be acceptable with certain pros and cons. For now, I've decided to extend ObservableCollection to fire events before any changes to the collections happen (e.g. before an item is added, deleted etc.) and allows subscribers to cancel those events. That way, I can use this class, and allow to implement certain validation logic by subscribing to the events and cancelling them, e.g. if an invalid item is tried to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Framework's [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It does pretty much what you need, but if anyway you still need to implement your own class, you can take ideas by looking at how it is implemented (which is by the way similar to your #2 approach).

Having said that, I personally think that #3 is also a very valid approach. Don't be afraid of writing long code (within reasonable limits of course) if the result is more readable and maintainable than it would be with shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with #2.

In #1 you just expose a entire collection of objects, allowing everyone to do anything with them.

#3 seems less self explanatory to me. Though - I like to keep thing simple when coding so I may be biased.

Answer (score 0):

If watchers are going to be shorter-lived than the thing being watched, I would avoid events.  The pattern exemplified by `ObservableCollection`, where the collection gives a subscribed observer an `IDisposable` object which can be used to unsubscribe is a much better approach.  If you use such a pattern, you can have your class hold a weak reference (probably use a "long" weak reference) to the the subscription object, which would in turn hold a strong reference (probably a delegate) to the subscriber and to the weak reference which identifies it.  Abandoned subscriptions will thus get cleaned up by the garbage collector; it will be the duty of a subscriber to ensure that a strongly-rooted reference exists to the subscription object.

Beyond the fact that abandoned subscriptions can get cleaned up, another advantage of using the 
"disposable subscription-object" approach is that unsubscription can easily be made lock-free and thread-safe, and run in constant time.  To dispose a subscription, simply null out the delegate contained therein.  If each attempt to add a subscription causes the subscription manager to inspect a couple of subscriptions to ensure that they are still valid, the total number of subscriptions in existence will never grow to more than twice the number that were valid as of the last garbage collection.